# urllib2 - counting number of lines in a .xlsx file - python

Tags: python, urllib

```
file_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/temp/aggregate_bill_export_20180427055420580970.xlsx'
meta = urllib.urlopen(file_url)

total_records = len(meta.readlines())

print total_records
```

Output that I'm getting:
Out[97]: 20

But this file contains only 10 records. However it returns correct count in case of .csv file. Please suggest what to do for .xlsx file.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't read `xlsx` file as the way you read normal text files. You need to use `xlrd` module for this.

First get the file and then use `xlrd` module to read that xlsx

```
In [12]: import requests

In [13]: import urllib

In [14]: import xlrd

In [15]: link = "http://f8f44d1e.ngrok.io/static/covernote_receipt/xyz.xlsx"

In [16]: file_name, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(link)

In [17]: workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)

In [18]: sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0) # Get your sheet here

In [19]: sheet
Out[19]: <xlrd.sheet.Sheet at 0x10fd3e090>

In [21]: sheet.nrows # No. of rows
Out[21]: 3

In [22]: sheet.ncols # No. of columns
Out[22]: 1

In [23]:
```

Here is my `xlsx` contents,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Rakesh. I beleive that you tried this for .txt file. Do try the same with any .xlsx file

Answer (score 0):

```
file_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/temp/aggregate_bill_export_20180427055420580970.xlsx'
meta = urllib.urlopen(file_url)

xlsx=meta.read()

wb = load_workbook(StringIO.StringIO(xlsx))

sheet = wb.worksheets[0]

total_records = sheet.max_row
```

Please review and suggest if something can be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is a text file that simply consists of rows separated by linebreaks. An Excel file is a binary file using a proprietary Microsoft format. For a CSV file the notion of "lines" makes sense. It is nonsensical for an Excel file.

If you want to count the rows in an Excel file you will have to use a library that can parse such a file. Just using `.readlines()` on the HTTP response body of an Excel file will not work.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for sharing this info